# Android Facebook app open link in fb webview and I can't login into my own web app

Tags: android, facebook, webview, facebook-login

I have a big problem with android native Facebook app with webview browser.
When I'm trying to click on mine CTA Facebook login button (own website) - nothing will happened.

There's problem with android webview, which can't open facebook modal login window.

I tried to use target="_blank" to open new window, but thats not right way.

Is there any solution to fix it?

Thanks so much,

Jacob.

Comment: Its simple solution to resolve this. You must implement your own Oauth2 Server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's simple easy solution to fix it. You must have a special own OauthServer to comunicate with api, and then sent to app its credentials.